# How to Find Which Stored Procedures have Grants

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How do I find stored procedures that require elevated privileges?

During testing of the application using the database, I discovered that some of the procedures required elevated privileges to run. As it turns out, there were GRANT statements in the stored procedures. Given that the database has over 600 stored procedures, I wrote the following to search the stored procedures for any GRANT statements.

```
/*
        NOTE: This script requires a Database Compatibility Level of 130 or higher.

        Use the following query to determine if your database meets the requirement
                select NAME,compatibility_level
                    from sys.databases

        You can update the database using the following query:
                ALTER DATABASE database_name   
                    SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130
--*/



declare         @process nvarchar(max)
            ,   @text   nvarchar(Max)

declare curProcs cursor 
    for (
            select distinct 
                        so.name
                    ,   sc.text
                from sys.sysobjects so
                    inner join sys.syscomments sc
                        on sc.id = so.id
                            and so.type = 'P'
                    where 
                        sc.text like '%grant[ ]%' 
            )

open curProcs

fetch next from curProcs into @process, @text

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

            begin try 
                ; with CTE as (
                                select @process [Process], value
                                    from STRING_SPLIT(  @text,  char(13) )
                                )
                            select * 
                                into #output
                                from cte 
                                    where 
                                        value like '%grant %'
                                            and
                                        value not like '%--%grant%'
            end try
            begin catch
            ; with CTE as (
                                select @process [Process], value
                                    from STRING_SPLIT(  @text,  char(13) )
                                )
                            insert into #output
                                select [Process], value
                                from cte 
                                    where 
                                        value like '%grant %'
                                            and
                                        value not like '%--%grant%'
            end catch

            fetch next from curProcs into @process, @text
    END

close curProcs
deallocate curProcs

select * from #output

drop table #output
```

Hope you find this useful. If there are improvements that can be made, please let me know.

Comment: If the intention is to provide an answer the correct format here is to start with a question. In your case something like "How do I find stored procedures that require elevated privileges?". Then you answer your own question. That way it makes it easier for others to find and provides closure to the question.

Comment: Thanks. I have not answered my own question before. This helps.